# How to speed up collect() from a dbconnect database

Tags: r, database, collect, dbplyr

I'm reading tables from an odbc driver on an amazonaws server.
I am using R 4.0.0 on a 64 bit windows computer.
Working from home and using company's VPN so my internet speed is about 17 Mbps download.

I connect to the database with this statement
*con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "databasename", timeout = 10)*

and I access the table with this statement
*case_tbl <- tbl(con, dbplyr::in_schema("fhv_owner", "case"))
case <- collect(case_tbl)*

The table has 500K rows and 60 columns, so it's not huge but it takes about 2 minutes to download.
Sometimes it takes 30 minutes if my internet is slow.

Is there any way to speed this up? Maybe something with data.table instead of dplyr?

I've tried filtering the columns I pick but sometimes I need more columns and have to rerun.

Maybe I just need to pay for faster internet.

Thanks,
Jennifer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you don't do here any data manipulation `data.table` won't help you speed up the process.
To make sure that the delay is due to your Internet connection speed and has nothing to do with `dbplyr`, use directly `DBI`:

```
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "databasename", timeout = 10)
system.time({case_tbl <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM fhv_owner.case")})
```

Comment: Thanks, that was pretty fast only 5 seconds

Comment: I would have bet on the Internet connection ;). If it answered your question ,could you accept it?

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking it's the internet. Because when I used to do it in the office without vpn it was very fast. Thanks for the help.

Comment: OK, I would have be surprised otherwise. Can you please accept the answer so that others know the question is closed? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your usecase and your database system, it might make sense to replace `odbc::odbc()` with `RPostgres::Postgres()` (if you have a postgres database that is, otherwise there are alternative packages...). This at least helped me a lot!